# R.java won't generate

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am currently working on a project in which I was updating a ListView's adapter from ArrayAdapter to a Custom CursorAdapter.

I deleted the R.java intentionally to regenerate the `R.java` file after inserting a new `<string></string>` to the `res/string.xml` file since it was not automatically regenerating. The file did not generate.

I continued to debug, and ran a `Project->Clean...` in attempt to regenerate the `R.java` file. This did not work either.

After checking StackOverflow, I also tried changing the version in AndroidManifest.xml in hope to regenerate the file. This also did not work. I've tried a few other hacks in hopes something might have Eclipse regenerate the file. No Luck.

Does anyone have any idea? I am on a tight deadline and this is really holding me back.

Here is the file I was working in when the issue arose:

```
package com.renaissanceartsmedia.gradingapp.controllers.fragments;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.renaissanceartsmedia.gradingapp.R;
import com.renaissanceartsmedia.gradingapp.controllers.activities.CourseActivity;
import com.renaissanceartsmedia.gradingapp.model.Course;
import com.renaissanceartsmedia.gradingapp.model.CourseStore;
import com.renaissanceartsmedia.gradingapp.model.GradingAppDatabaseHelper.CourseCursor;

public class CourseListFragment extends ListFragment {

    // DEBUG
    private static final String TAG = "CourseListFragment";

    // Create an ArrayList<String> to store flashcards
    ArrayList<Course> mCourses;
    ArrayMap<Long, Course> mCoursesById;

    // Cursor Object
    private CourseCursor mCursor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the Title of the Fragment's Activity
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.course_list);

        // Load Cursor to DB
        mCursor = CourseStore.get(getActivity()).queryCourses();

        // Set the list of FlashcardListFragments
        mCourses = CourseStore.get(getActivity()).getCourses();
        mCoursesById  = CourseStore.get(getActivity()).getCoursesById();

        // Create an ArrayAdapter to use for displaying FlashcardListFragments in FlashcardListActivity
        /*
        ArrayAdapter<Flashcard> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Flashcard>(
                                                                    getActivity(),
                                                                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                                                    mFlashcards);
        */

        // OLD METHOD
        //ListItemLayoutAdapter adapter = new ListItemLayoutAdapter(mCourses);
        CourseCursorAdapter adapter = new CourseCursorAdapter(getActivity(), mCursor);

        // Set the adapter for the list
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }


    /* Handles a user selection of a FlashcardListFragment
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        //Flashcard f = (Flashcard)(getListAdapter()).getItem(position);
        // OLD WAY
        //Course c = ((ListItemLayoutAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);

        /*
        Course c = ((CourseCursorAdapter))getListAdapter());
        Log.d(TAG, c.getCourseTitle() + " was clicked");


        // Start a new activity using an Intent
        Intent openFlashcardDetail = new Intent(getActivity(), CourseActivity.class);

        // Add EXTRAS to the intent
        //openFlashcardDetail.putExtra(FlashcardFragment.EXTRA_FLASHCARD_ID, f.getId());
        openFlashcardDetail.putExtra(Course.EXTRA_COURSE_ID, c.getId());

        startActivity(openFlashcardDetail);
        */

    }

    // OLD METHOD
    //class ListItemLayoutAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Course> {
    class CourseCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

        // Member Properties
        // OLD METHOD
        Course mCurrentListObject;
        CourseCursor mCourseCursor;

        // Constructor
        // OLD METHOD
        /*
        public ListItemLayoutAdapter(ArrayList<Course> itemContent) {
            super(getActivity(), 0, itemContent);

        }
        */

        public CourseCursorAdapter(Context context, CourseCursor cursor) {
            super(context, cursor, 0);
            mCourseCursor = cursor;
        }
        // OLD WAY
        /*
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //If we weren't given a view, inflate a new view
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                        .inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, null);
            }

            // Configure the view for this object
            mCurrentListObject = getItem(position);

            // Make Connections from Layout to Java code
            TextView mainTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_main_text);
            TextView subTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_sub_text);

            // Set the Contents of the Views
            mainTextView.setText(setMainText());
            subTextView.setText(setSubText());

            return convertView;
        }
        */

        @Override 
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Use a layout Inflater to get a row view
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            return inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

            // Get the course for the current row
            Course course = mCourseCursor.getCourse();

            // Setup a new TextView
            TextView courseTitleTextView = (TextView)view;
            String mainText = context.getString(R.string.course_title_hint, course.getCourseTitle());
            courseTitleTextView.setText(mainText);


        }



        public String setMainText() {
            return mCurrentListObject.getCourseTitle();
        }
        public String setSubText() {
            return mCurrentListObject.getSubject();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any erros? Try checking Problems and Console tabs.

Comment: you just deleted R or the whole gen folder?

Comment: All my Errors are related to the R.java file not existing. Either references to strings or layouts and R.java import statements.

Comment: Make sure you don't have errors in the res folder, because they are more difficult to notice. Errors in layout prevent the adk of building the R file so you see a lot of errors about Missing R.

Comment: I just deleted the R and not the whole gen folder

Comment: Check all of your xml files for errors. Not only layouts. also check that you don't have invalid characters in file names (such as CAPS or -)

Comment: delete the whole gen folder should help

Comment: The R.java is not generating back because you have error, either in your code or in your layouts. So, make sure to check your files which were the last one, and correct them if there are any error.

Comment: I just checked strings.xml and all eight layouts I had for errors by adding and deleting white space and reserving. There are no erros. I also tried deleting the whole gen folder. No success.

Comment: The R.java does not build if you have errors in any of your xml files. I have also heard of people updating their android sdk build tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solution, I hope this will help you. !!

### Step 1) Change Build Target

For Example, if you selected 2.2 as Build Target then select Maximum you have. (like 4.4)

And if you selected 4.4 then select 4.3 as target.

[image: Build Target]

### Step 2) Clean Project

[image: Clean Project]

### It will create R.java again

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens because there is an issue somewhere in your XML or resource file names.
Try restarting Eclipse, if it still does not indicate where the problem is, try retracing your steps the last changes you made to XML files before this problem occurred. You will find some kind of syntax error or spelling mistake or invalid file name somewhere. Fix it then clean again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Eclipse open your problems view (Window -> Show view -> Problems) and look for an error in your resources or manifest

Comment: No errors listed in the 'problems' pane related to the rsc or the manifest

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting eclipse, sometimes it will do the trick. Check if you are using jdk 7, it only needs jdk 6.